# How to pass a variable from HTML form and DropList to the PHP file using "get"

Tags: php, html

I want to change this code...

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" name="form1" id="form1">
<select name="name">
  <option value="category">CATEGORY</option>
  <option value="product">PRODUCT</option>
</select>
<input name="value" type="text" id="catprod" size="20" />
```

At the end I want to receive a link of type...

http://www.mysite.com/search.php?product=car

or

http://www.mysite.com/search.php?category=auto

depends of what item from the drop list will choose a customer. "Car" and "Auto" are search requests from the customers, which they will type in.

Comment: And your question is? You have to change the names of the input fields (select, input) according to your requirements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function redirect() {
                window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/search.php?'+document.form1.key.value+'='+document.form1.val.value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="redirect(); return false;">
        <select name="key">
           <option value="category">CATEGORY</option>
           <option value="product">PRODUCT</option>
        </select>
        <input name="val" type="text" id="catprod" />
    </form>
</html>
```

your javascript and html are mainly seperated this way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are 2 methods of doing this.

The first one is change the input name of for text-field to the correct name (category or product) when de select is changed. So you make a

```
onChange="document.getElementById('catprod').name = this.value;"
```

Watch out that on loading you give the input the correct name already. Under normal conditions that would be "category" (because that is selected as first one).

Another option is to make 2 input fields with 1 hidden. And you show the field that the user has selected. (also with a onchange, but then using hide and show).

Anyway, this both would not be the best way to solve the problem. The best problem is just by solving it in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" name="form1" id="form1">
<select style="border:1px solid rgb(102,153,204);background-color:FFFFCC;height:20px;width:120px;" onfocus="this.style.background='white'" onblur="this.style.background='FFFFCC'" name="name" id="myselect">
                              <option value="category">CATEGORY</option>
                              <option value="product">PRODUCT</option>
                            </select>
<input name="value" type="text" id="catprod" style="border:1px solid rgb(102,153,204);background-color:FFFFCC;height:15px;width:200px;" onfocus="this.style.background='white'" onblur="this.style.background='FFFFCC'" size="20" />

<script>
  var submitform = function() {
   form1.submit();  
  }
  document.getElementById('myselect').onchange = submitform;
</script>
```

I strongly suggest not using inline css as you're using and giving more meaningful names to your IDs (and classes). Also, avoid using inline JS.

What the code in the script tag does, is submit the form when you change the value on the select element. Since your form uses method "get", you'll have those types of URLs when you submit the form.

Comment: And you approved the one above? :)